# developing custodial vs non-custodial wallets

Tags: web3js, blockchain, wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp

This is a very broad and general question so I'm going to specify my intended use case and branch several questions, mainly referring to the implementation of each approach.

In short, users using my wallet are going to constantly send to each other, and perhaps receive/send from/to other wallets and networks, and I'm mentioning this in case it could provide an overview of how transactions will take place in my app.

- so to start with the custodial wallets:from what i know, most custodial wallets have 1 cold wallet and 1 hot wallet and a hot wallet to every user, so when a user creates an account keys are automatically generated to that user, but my question is how are the users' keys stored: is it in a normal db or do they do it in another way, and how does this model work like how do they technically use the cold and hot wallets.
- moving to non-custodial wallets,i want to know basically the same thing, how and where are the users' keys stored? and how are they accessed? and in case i go with this approach i am still able to impose tx fees on tx happening on my app?

I hope I made sense in what I said, and I hope to check your answers, If you feel like you know an answer to some part of the question but not all that okay say what you know as any contribution would be great, and if anyone is up for a discord/zoom call i would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance, and please let me know in case you need extra info to answer.

Comment: These questions are out of scope for the site since they are not related to Ethereum. Some wallets use HSM (hardware security modules) or a secure service like aws CloudHSM, HashiCorp Vault.

Comment: @Ismael ,thanks for your reply, so how would i go about using an HSM ,I've researched a bit now but i thought id ask you incase you know of some articl/video/resource i could benefit from. thanks in advance